# Making a DLL of a User Control plus Jquery embeded in

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I found some related resources and some years ago I had similar but unique experiences near this subject.

Now I'm looking for doing this :
Embed **`Jquery` and a `plugin`** inside `a user control` or a `composite control` e.g with some `labels or repeater` , ...
and make a DLL output of it

the control should enforce the checking of scripts priorities
First `Jquery` and then the `plugin`

At last could make it as a **reuasable DLL**

thanks in advance

Edit : The Path,Best-Practice,information or simple example of it's most trickiest parts is appreciated
please look at my below comment

Comment: If you are on nothing at the moment, that is more of a project than a question. IF you talk .NET you have embedded resource and you can have help Googling on Composite Control where you use i.e. RenderControl event to tell .NET print and html / js from code to client.

Comment: Man I didn't ask for the whole code, There should be 2-3 tricky parts that I asked for the best-practices of doing it, one is about the scripts priority which we want to embed, and also wanted to know whether will doing so affect making a DLL of it ?

Comment: I've done it a few times with the concept of Composite Controls. Even a "CombinedScripts" control who's only purpose is to load scripts and/or CSS to the client. In the RenderControl you can have as much statements as you want.

Comment: So you should understand me, could you please give me a piece of your "RenderControl" code that prevent me from going wrong or use a try and fix approach, it could be helpful, thanks

Comment: CombinedScripts is really similar to what I have in mind, with the exception of I wanted to make a "Resources" assembly in a mission and make a standalone control with a similar pattern in another mission

Comment: I think I do. I hoped that short reply let you into an idea while someone else may come with a better answer. Im not able to give better reply at this monent.

Comment: I put a +1 on it, hopefully it will give me some hints, my problem is just time, thanks my friend

Comment: Hold on, someone apparently has a decent answer to this.

Comment: @Will Thank's. Now this was commented on META (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124610/158494) and I did a new question/answer (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9571400/625103). But now, with this re-opened, I put my reply in here also. I hope it's not appears repeatetive.

Comment: @will , when I have any question here is the place I'll be in, I took my decision after minutes of search and study and built the control and the strategy, Although here are good people to share, when you do not have the question so ... ! anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have some technically tricky parts and I try to cover them here. I onced spent some time on Google until I finally got all pieces. I surely can't help you with all of them. Some of them are very local to the actual scenario. In fact, I did never found any suitable information to my scenario, that didn't lead me to a spaghetti-code, hughe code base and so on.

You create a Composite Control by simply override  System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Webcontrol in a new class. I use CombinedScript as a name due to your interest of it. The name can of course be anything.

```
public class CombinedScript : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
{

}
```

While override that, you have some methods to use. There are several methods then those below, but you have to google on what best suites your need.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
}
```

The point is that the methods are doing things before, while and after the generate of the controls content to client. The OnPreRender occurs before, I.e.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    ClientScriptManager cs = this.Page.ClientScript;
    cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(WebControls.CombinedScript), "Project.Script.Common.js");
    cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(WebControls.CombinedScript), "Project.Script.JQuery.js");
    cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(WebControls.CombinedScript), "Project.Script.JCharts.js");
}
```

A tricky thing here is the path to scripts. "Project" is the DLL assembly base name. "Script" is the case sensitive path, where the script files are located (counted from project base path). The last part is the case sensitive name of the file. I'm not sure, but I think the path trick is no question if you leave exact everything at root.

WebControls.CombinedScript is, as you can see, the name of the control. To be used in ASP.NET pages, it has to be registered in web.config.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Project" tagPrefix="myname" namespace="Project.WebControls" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Those RegisterClientScriptResource makes the scripts being loaded as `GET /WebResource.axd?d=MTVCK_diZif7wEDQp9UGv-GlqPKP-WXGPNEqr-mq_RnUKWDgSydkLxIuSusdnolRQsR-wpNbTpfJzAVtsonjuwVUqzguotspQFImk6-auSF3N18eVOXbYh_-6NHovgR90&t` when the site are loaded. If they don't, there are something wrong. I.e. wrong path, forgotten to include js as embedded resource and so on.

When all above is done, you register the DLL, add the namespace / control tag and then put it on your page with `<myname:CombinedScript runat="server" />`

You can probably do something like this, add public properties to the Composite Control
`public int ScriptType {get;set;}`. Put the attribute to the control `<myname:CombinedScript ScriptType="1" runat="server" />`. and add `if (this.ScriptType == 1) { ..evaluate what script to load.. }`. Of course that type of evaluation can be altered from clientside (anyone can replace their generated html to another ScriptType ID).

I think you can investigate yourself better by this. You want statements that evaluate what scripts to load. The last sample above is one way and you can of course put any kind of logic between / on the RegisterClientScriptResources.

I was talked about RenderControl and Render.
You can use it like this,

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    HttpResponseSubstitutionCallback callback = new HttpResponseSubstitutionCallback(outputcache_callback);
    Context.Response.WriteSubstitution(callback);
}

public static string outputcache_callback(HttpContext context)
{
    string html = "";

    html += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    html += " var lang='" + Project.Common.CurrentLang + " ';";
    html += " var applicationPath='" + GetApplicationPath + "'; ";
    html += "</script>";
    return html;
}

public GetApplicationPath { get { ..logic.. }}
```

That's another kind of technique put scripts into clientside. Good if you which to have user- or instance-specific variables loaded to your scripts. `static` is for the substitution-sample. Also, if you want to affect the generating of content of the control itself (like if you would make a smarter asp:Label, you can do so,

```
public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.RenderControl(writer);
    writer.Write("<div id='dvBox'>");
    ....
    base.RenderChildren(writer);
    writer.Write("</div>");
    writer.Write(script);
}
```

I hope that are information that combine and help several developers out there searching for such way to build controls.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I hope I try it in my near projects or as a good practice, it could be useful ;)