# Embedding Scripts Loading in Order

Tags: jquery, asp.net, embedded-resource

I formerly asked for a Best-Practice regarding this,
But this is one the strategies
Here is the situation we'll go:

1. we want to first add **JQuery** to the Page (as an example via the
   **Web Resources** )
2. after that load a **library**
3. The Library is using a template named :

   ```
   "Hello sticky hide"
   ```
4. Add the Library-User Code **Ready Blah blah blah**

I want to complete this practice at least for my own.
Maybe It simply be fixed just by adding line, removing a char or changing place

but any idea and hopefully the fix is appreciated

It doesn't show any error but there is no result.

```
[assembly: WebResource("Quad.WebControls.JQuery.js", "application/x-javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("Quad.WebControls.ProHello.js", "application/x-javascript")]
namespace Quad.WebControls
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:QuadBar runat=server></{0}:QuadBar>")]
    public class QuadBar : WebControl
    {
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            if (!DesignMode)
            {
                //ClientScriptManager cs ;
                ScriptManager sm= ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

                if (sm == null)
                    throw new HttpException("Error");

                string scriptJQuery = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "Quad.WebControls.JQuery.js");
                string scriptjqHello = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "Quad.WebControls.ProHello.js");


                HtmlGenericControl jq = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
                 ...

                HtmlGenericControl jqHello = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
                 ...      

                Page.Header.Controls.Add(jq);
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(jqHello);


        //-------           

**RenderControl**
```

public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.RenderControl(writer);

```
    //StringBuilder sbInit = new StringBuilder();


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(" <script type=\"text/javascript\"> ")
        .Append("  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endrequest(EndRequestHandler); ")
        .Append("$(document).ready(function () {")
          ...
        .Append("});")
        .Append("</script>");

    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

**The Aspx Part -** (The Control is registered          )
Form - Placed inside the Asp.Net Form

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

  <div class="Hello sticky hide">
        <p>
            MHM Message</p>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:">
            <img src="images/icon-close.png" /></a>
    </div>

<Quad:QuadBar runat="server" ID="proHello" />



    <div class="wrapper">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="round green button" id="sticky"><span>Sticky bar</span></a> will
                remain visible even user scroll the page.</li>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer could be found here :
[Making a DLL of a User Control plus Jquery embeded in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558933/making-a-dll-of-a-user-control-plus-jquery-embeded-in)

although it could be counted as a duplicate of one of my questions